# how to persist the firefox temporay addon on browser restart

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I had created a **chrome extension** and it's working fine. So I'm trying to use the same extension in the firefox also. and I modified the configs for the firefox and made it work. Like I added the unpacked extension in chrome I added the temporary extension in firefox but the extension is disappearing when restarts the firefox browser. So after reading the documentation I set the config of the firefox and modified to

```
xpinstall.signatures.required  false

extensions.langpacks.signatures.required  false
```

after that I tried loading, then also the **temporary extension is not persisting** after the **restart**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my question

**Using web-ext**

web-ext is a node-based application that you install with the nodejs/npm tool. Install web-ext using the following command:

```
npm install --global web-ext
```

Signing your extension for self-distribution

https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/publish/signing-and-distribution-overview/

```
web-ext sign --api-key=$AMO_JWT_ISSUER --api-secret=$AMO_JWT_SECRET
```

upload the xpi file on **about:addons**

**Zipped files**

zip the temporary addon and rename and modify the extension to xpi and upload to **about:addons**

Answer (score 2):

Temporarily installed add-ons will be temporary and removed on restart.

You can install unsigned extensions in Firefox Nightly or Firefox Developer edition.
Standard Firefox release will not allow permanent installation of unsigned add-ons.